# Find the value of $z \in\mathbb C$ such that $|z| - z = 5+9i$ express answer in exact form.

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the value of $z \in\mathbb C$ such that $|z| - z = 5+9i$ express answer in exact form.

Comment: Good question. What progress have you made toward solving it?

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$z=x+iy$$ then your equation is equal to $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x-iy=5+9i$$
You will get
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-5-x-i(9+y)=0$$